# Expected height of a random forest

Tags: asymptotics, expected-value, trees, random-graphs

Consider unlabeled rooted forests with $n$ nodes. What is the expected height of such a forest? I'm actually interested in the asymptotic as $n \to \infty$. Surely it's something like $\log n$, but my searches came up empty, and I imagine I just don't know where to look. Here "height" is the maximal number of nodes in a path starting at a root of a tree in the forest.

Edit: The most relevant OEIS sequence I found was [A291336](https://oeis.org/A291336), though it doesn't give much in the way of references or immediately answer the question.

Comment: Are you choosing uniformly at random from the set of all forests with n total nodes?

Comment: @Adam Yes, I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average height of an *ordered* rooted forest with $n$ nodes is known to be asymptotically $\sqrt{\pi n}$.  See [N. Dershowitz, C. Rinderknecht, “The Average Height of Catalan Treesby Counting Lattice Paths”](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enachumd/papers/AverageHeight.pdf).  (A rooted forest is just a rooted tree with the root removed.)

Because a taller unordered forest can be expected to have less branching and therefore fewer orderings than a shorter unordered forest, the average unordered rooted forest should be a little bit taller than an average ordered rooted forest.  Numerical evidence agrees; compare [A001853](https://oeis.org/A001853)(*n* + 1)/[A000081](https://oeis.org/A000081)(*n* + 1) with [A136439](https://oeis.org/A136439)(*n*)/[A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108)(*n*):

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, great references! I explored further from there, and another recent and relevant paper is [Broutin--Flajolet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.1515.pdf). They obtain a $c\sqrt{n}$ asymptotic for unlabeled, rooted, unordered, *binary* trees. They discuss some difficulties arising from the unordered case in the intro. As far as I can tell my exact problem is open (i.e. remove "binary" from Broutin--Flajolet), but the conjecture would be $c\sqrt{n}$. Broutin--Flajolet would seem to suggest a sufficiently astute singularity analysis may be the right approach.